# Will programs designed for Windows 7 work on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility

One of the main questions slowing me from upgrading to Windows 8 is backwards-compatibility. I have many programs from smaller companies that I know will not be able to come up with a windows 8-specific version for a long time, so **will I be able to use Windows 7 versions on Windows 8?**

Comment: your answer - it depends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Kevin Turner, Microsoft's COO said at the Worldwide Partner Conference 2011.“The gateway to get to Windows 8 is Windows 7, and we will have backward compatibility with Windows 7 embedded into Windows 8. That's something that we're very committed to. But that's a really important first pillar,”.
So according to Microsoft answer is yes.

source is: http://www.tomshardware.com/news/windows-win8-win7-software-compatibility,13085.html

Comment: please cite your source.

Comment: @Sathya now source is there

Answer (score 0):

A magazine article I read said that Windows 8 does provide backward compatibility for Windows 7 programs, so yes they should work on Windows 8.

Comment: "a magazine article you've read" is not a proper source of information

Answer (score -2):

Yes, all applications made in the last 10 years or so will work. MS works very hard to make sure that software (1st and 3rd party) remains usable..